# Using php session_start() again when loading more HTML, using jQuery Load() function

Tags: php, jquery, session

So i have a small piece of PHP/HTML code that is loaded inside a DIV element using jQuery load() function as follows.

main file

```
<!doctype=HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <?PHP   session_start();  
    $_SESSION['user'] = 'BartSimpson';
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 'Ok.. but its Bart';
    ?>
    <script src="JQUERY_file.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
     <div id="Main_div"></div>
     <button id="but_ton">click here</button
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

jQuery file

```
$(document).ready(
$("#but_ton").click(function(){
    $("#Main_div").load("small_php.php");
});
);
```

small_php.php

```
<H1><?PHP session_start();
    echo "Session var is" . $_SESSION['valid']; ?>
    echo "User is" . $_SESSION['user']; ?>
</H1>
```

In the beginning, I only had ONE *session_start()* at the beginning of main file. And when I click on the button to load the 'small_php.php' file, I wasn't able to echo the session variables indide the dynamic H1 tag.
However, by fluke, when I thought about it a little, I decided to add *session_start* to the beginning of the 'small_php.php' file, and now I was able to echo the session variable inside the dynamic H1 tag. But thing is, I am reading everywhere that having two *session_start()* on the same page is not good practice. I get that is the case for a single HTML page with no dynamic content, but what if the dynamic content kinda needs to read the Session Variables?
So my question is: Is there anything wrong with this code? Is there fundamentally something wrong with my understanding? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?
Many, many thanks in Advance.

Comment: FYI, it's [`<!DOCTYPE html>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype)

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `session_start()`  that way. You are combining two pages into one, but it still counts as two pages for PHP, so therefore it doesn't not go against the one `session_start()` per page practice.

Comment: thanks a lot @JM-AGMS, so much appreciated!!